# how to parse this xml in jquery to get an attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I need to parse the following example XML in jquery, to get the attribute "V"

XML file:

```
<RES>
<R N="1">
    <MT N="myMeta1" V="myMeta1Value"/>
    <MT N="myMeta2" V="myMeta2Value"/>
    <MT N="myMeta2" V="myMeta2Value"/>
</R>
</RES>
```

And my javascript is the following:

```
function(data){
$(data).find('R').each(function(){
    var $result = $(this);
    $result.find('MT').each(function(_mt) {
            console.log($(_mt).attr("V") );
    });
});
```

}

I get undefineds, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument to `.each` callback is the index, the second one is the value. You can also use `this`:

```
$result.find('MT').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("V") );
});
```

Or:

```
$result.find('MT').each(function( index, _mt ) {
        console.log($(_mt).attr("V") );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are `using index as an element in each`. As first parameter is index pass two parameter in each and use the second to get the element.

```
function(data){
  $(data).find('R').each(function(){
      var $result = $(this);
      $result.find('MT').each(function(_mt, obj) {
            console.log($(obj).attr("V") );
      });
   });
}
```